# Making '*' key on keypad a backspace key

Tags: arduino-mega, keyboard

Using a 4x3 membrane keypad and I want to make the '*' key a backspace if the wrong number is entered.

I am a newbie and having a hard time trying to figure out how to code that, any help would be great.

```cpp
int getNumber()
{
  int num = 0;
  char key = myKeypad.getKey();
  while (digitCount <=  1)
  {
    switch (key)

    {
    case NO_KEY:
      break;
    case '0':     
    case '1':     
    case '2':     
    case '3':     
    case '4':    
    case '5': 
    case '6':     
    case '7':     
    case '8':     
    case '9':
      num = num * 10 + (key -  48);
      digitCount++;
      break;
    case '*':
      break;
    case '#':
      break;
    }
  key = myKeypad.getKey();
  }

  digitCount = 0;
  return num;
}
```

Comment: Divide your number by 10?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean.

Comment: To make room to add a number you multiply by Ten. So to remove that space you divide by 10.

Comment: `case '*': num /= 10; break;` and then you need to echo that to the display (if any).